# Couldn't revert downvote when answer edited during grace period

Tags: support, grace-period, locked-votes

I downvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26128048/852828) because it recommended a really terrible library. The author edited the reference out during the initial 5 minute (?) grace period.

I didn't get back to the answer for a while, and when I did I was unable to reverse the downvote because the question had not been edited, as far as the system was concerned, and it was too long since my downvote had happened so it was "locked in".

Is there anything that can be done about this?

Comment: It's still a low quality answer, as it's just suggesting the use of a framework with almost no other information.

Comment: Wait for it to be edited again or ask the author for trivial edit.